# How can I deep link to a page in Control Panel?

Tags: control-panel

I need to access the Network Connections page often to change adapter settings. How can I save clicks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The control panel accepts command line arguments. Create a shortcut to target:

```
control.exe netconnections
```

The argument `netconnections` causes `control.exe` to open directly to Network Connections. Many other arguments are documented in [Microsoft: Executing Control Panel Items](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/shell/executing-control-panel-items).

Name the shortcut "Network Connections - Adapter Settings" and it will be searchable from the Start menu (press Win key, type "adapter").